# Using conditions from another model inside a model method using CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

In my app I have three tables:

```
Users
Profiles
Friends
```

The User has one Profile and Profiles have one User and have many Friends. Friends have many Profiles.

In the Profile model I have a method that gets a list of Profiles for a Profile (BUT it uses the related username which comes from the user table.)

```
public function getFriends($username) {

   return $this->find('all', array(
     'conditions' => array(
       'User.username' => $username,
        'Friend.status' => 1
      )
   ));

}
```

So it should be getting a list of profiles that match where the username matches a User and Friend status is 1. How do I do this though?

I'll also post my associations so you can understand the DB:

**User Model:**

```
public $hasOne = 'Profile';
```

**Profile Model:**

```
public $belongsTo = 'User';

public $hasMany = array(
    'ProfileFrom'=>array(
        'className'=>'Friend',
        'foreignKey'=>'profile_from'
    ),
    'ProfileTo'=>array(
        'className'=>'Friend',
        'foreignKey'=>'profile_to'
    )
);

public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Friendship' => array(
        'className' => 'Profile',
        'joinTable' => 'friends',
        'foreignKey' => 'profile_from',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'profile_to'
    )
);

public $actsAs = array('Containable');
```

**Friend Model:**

```
public $belongsTo = array(
      'UserFrom'=>array(
         'className'=>'Profile',
         'foreignKey'=>'profile_from'
      ),
      'UserTo'=>array(
         'className'=>'Profile',
         'foreignKey'=>'profile_to'
      )
   );

public $actsAs = array('Containable');
```

Comment: It looks a bit more complicated than needed. Why User HasOne Profile ? That makes it just part of the user so doesn't need to be separated in another model? Don't you just need 2 tables: users and relations? In relatations just put friend1_id and friend2_id and that's it?

Comment: A user doesn't necessarily have a profile! But that's NOT the point of this question rather how to pull from other models for setting up the conditions.

Comment: Oh, that's simple. A long as the models have relations, you can access the others methods and attributes through (assuming Post hasMany Comment, example code located in Post model) `$this-> Comment->someMethod()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks complicated, I'd suggest having a look at Containable (a core cakephp behavior) which makes selecting which data to fetch a lot easier (especially with regards to preventing selecting too much data). Please consider using that for your whole app.

It seems you're trying to tell cake to search in associated Friend model, but if I'm right the only associations existing to the friend  are aliased as ProfileTo and ProfileFrom. So I'm guessing cake won't know where to fiend 'Friend'. But in the future it would be helpful to post any errors as well.

See my suggestion below for a possible fix.

---

For now you could do the following:
In ProfileModel:

```
function getFriends($username) {
    //Start by getting User's ID
    $user = $this->User->find(
        'first',
        array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'User.username' => $username
            )
        )
    );
    //User's ID is now $user['User']['id']

    //Fetch user's profile with associated friends
    $this->Behaviors->attach('Containable');
    $profileAndFriends = $this->find(
        'first',  //Because User hasOne Profile, so we'll fetch this one profile.
        array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'Profile.user_id' => $user['User']['id']
            ),
            //We'll want to fetch all associated Friend records (which are linked to the Profile model as ProfileFrom and ProfileTo
            'contain' => array(
                'ProfileFrom' => array(
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'status' => 1
                    )
                ),
                'ProfileTo' => array(
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'status' => 1
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );
    return $profileAndFriends;
}
```

It should work like this. So in FriendsController you should now be able to do `$this->Friend->UserTo->getFriends('cameron');` 
That should fetch the profile belonging to the user with username 'cameron', and all Friends associated with this profile.

---

There's one small thing still bothering me though, and that's the fact that you got an error stating that ProfileTo isn't associated with Profile, which is weird as in your example that relation is obviously defined.
The cause might be a fault in the definition of your associations, but I'm not sure.

---

One more suggestion, if the above code doesn't work, replace the `contain` array with:

```
            'contain' => array(
                'Friendship' => array(
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'OR' => array(
                            'Friendship.profile_from' => 'Profile.id',
                            'Friendship.profile_to' => 'Profile.id',
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
```

Comment: Why have you used 'first' instead of 'all'?

Comment: Also that code gives me this error: `Warning (512): Model "Profile" is not associated with model "ProfileTo" [CORE/Cake/Model/Behavior/ContainableBehavior.php, line 339]`

Comment: I used 'first' because a user has only one profile. So I'd fetch that profile, and with it all related Friends.
The error you report shouldn't occur though, as you've defined an association with ProfileTo in your ProfileModel, that's still there, right?

Comment: Wait a sec, which CakePHP version are you using? I was assuming 1.3, but the path in your error looks more like 2.0...

Comment: I've done a small update to the code example. I don't really see how it could have caused the error, but you never know... Could you please retry?

Comment: Well it won't work anyways because the Friends are linked to a profile id but I get the profiles via the username which is in the User table. So it's a combination of 3 tables!

Comment: Okay, so let's start from the beginning. In which Model/Controller do you want to call this function?

Comment: It's called from the FriendsController and should take a username so e.g `/people/cameron/friends/` and then for that User get their profile and linked friends and then display a list of profiles for that username that are friends.

Comment: Updated answer again. Hope this helps.

Comment: And updated answer again with an extra suggestion (the last bit)

Comment: No problem! Glad it wasn't all for nothing ;)